# NSString drawInRect with stroke cause incorrect new line in IOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I need draw string with stroke ,then convert to a UIImage, but in ios 13.7, the "stroke" 's new line not match to "fill" 's new line,

error in ios 13.7:
[image: error in ios 13.7]

correct in ios 14 ,16:
[image: correct in ios 14 ,16]

after some test ,i find if i don't set NSParagraphStyleAttributeName in attributes, new line is right in ios 13.7 ,it's a bug in ios 13.7?

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIImage *img = [[self class] drawTextWithStroke];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];    
}

+ (UIImage*)drawTextWithStroke
{

    NSString* string = @"The operation couldn’t be completed. completed";

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 362, 42);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];

    // retina display, double resolution
   if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f) {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2.0f);
   } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
   }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    attributes[ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ] = style;
    
    // draw stroke
    [attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3] forKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
    [string drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

    // draw fill
    [attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [string drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
    
    // convert to image and return
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: Why not set all of the stroke and fill attributes together and draw the string just once. Why two separate passes?

Comment: @HangarRash you mean ``` CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeSize);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColorRef);
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context ,fillColor);
                [string drawInRect:drawArea withAttributes:drawAttrs];``` ? ,i tried ,but found CGContextSetLineWidth not working and fillColor is always black

Comment: No. I mean populate `attributes` once with both fill and stroke keys and values then call `[string drawInRect` just once with all of the attributes.

Comment: @HangarRash i tried this [attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3] forKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [string drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];  ,the result font is not fill ,it is hollow

Comment: Did you get a chance to try the solution in the answer below?